# Calculate Text SUM in Different Column in R

Tags: r

I just started R so this is must be a newbie questions.
Tried several ways but no luck crack the problem.

I want to calculate the sum of exact value in column 1 & 2. E.g. i want to sum the "archer orange" & "archer apple"

**Case**
Archer | Apple
Archer   | Orange
Hunter  | Orange
Archer   | Apple
Hunter   | Apple

**Output**

Archer Orange | 1
Archer Apple  | 2

CMIIW, tried as.data.frame(table(a$id))
but only works for 1 column not 2 columns condition.

Comment: Can you explain what means "sum" ? You want count how many rows with 1 & 2? why `Hunter | Orange` doesnt in your output? if you need `count` then you can create additional colunm usinng `paste` and then `group_by` as in your previous questoin.

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(table(do.call(paste0, df1)))`